# Authentication for several sub-domains

Tags: node.js, backend

Good afternoon everyone.

In the team we plan to make n applications that are very different from the others but we need that with a single time that the user authenticates he has access to all of them.

The applications will be under a single domain.

- `domain.com`
- `app1.domain.com`
- `app2.domain.com`
- `app3.domain.com`

So we want to implement an authentication scheme very similar to google's, where 2 additional subdomains are managed:

- `accounts.domain.com:` to handle all authentication rules (eg login, signup, forgot password, etc.)
- `myaccount.domain.com:` to manage all the user's personal information, subscriptions, security settings, etc.

The questions are as follows:

1. What is the safest and best way to do this?
2. What database-level considerations should we take into account?
3. What general considerations should we take into account to avoid
   future problems?

For what it's worth, the stack we are going to use is `nestjs` + `mongodb` + `graphql`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and safest way to manage this is to use a proxy that accesses the services instead of the user directly communicating with them. Then they only have to authenticate against the proxy.

Your other options require some sort of central authentication provider. This could be done a number of ways (assuming you control all the involved services). You could use a shared cross domain cookie or use some sort of oauth flow depending on your requirements.

Comment: Hi @Deadron. Thanks for answering. I really like the proxy approach but I have one doubt. Currently I use Angular for the frontend and I save the token in the Localstorage. The changes that would take part are that instead of saving the token in Localstorage I should create a Cross-Domain cookie and save it there?

Comment: @JuanGarcia If you are using a proxy it means that your frontend is only communicating with one backend and you can use traditional cookie based session management. You dont need cross domain cookies or anything special and can plug in a standard authentication system.

Comment: I would have several frontend applications, that means that all of them would communicate with a single proxy?

Comment: @JuanGarcia If they are all participating in the same authentication system and communicating with the same set of services then unless there are some other requirements I would say yes.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you very much.